# How to set checkbox value to true using button in tkinterGUI

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I set all the check box to true by using button function in selectAllRating?
Below is my code
Please advise

```
for i in range(5):
    option = StringVar(value="")
    starCheckBox.append(option)

Checkbutton(master, text='5 Stars',variable=starCheckBox[0], onvalue="5", offvalue="").place(x=0,y=20)
Checkbutton(master, text='4 Stars',variable=starCheckBox[1], onvalue="4", offvalue="").place(x=100,y=20)
Checkbutton(master, text='3 Stars',variable=starCheckBox[2], onvalue="3", offvalue="").place(x=200,y=20)
Checkbutton(master, text='2 Stars',variable=starCheckBox[3], onvalue="2", offvalue="").place(x=300,y=20)
Checkbutton(master, text='1 Stars',variable=starCheckBox[4], onvalue="1", offvalue="").place(x=400,y=20)

Button(master, text='Select all Hotel(s)', command=selectAllHotel).place(x=0,y=190)

def selectAllRating():
   for i in starCheckBox:
      i.set('1')
```

Answer (score 2):

The Checkbutton has a method to select it, it is called `select` and also has a `deselect` method for the opposite.

```
def selectAllRating():
   for i in starCheckBox:
      i.select()
```

If you want just to set the Checkbutton in a different state as it was before, you could use `toggle`.
If you want to `toggle` and run the associated `command` you can use `invoke`. All of these methods will be reflected by the associated `variable`.

[See the documentation for more inforamtion](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/checkbutton.html)

---

**Edit:**

> StringVar not able to do so?

Yes it is, but you need to set the associated `variable` to the `onvalue`.

> In addition, each checkbutton monitors its associated variable and
> automatically selects and deselects itself when the variables value
> changes to and from the button's “on”, “off” and “tristate” values.

So your code would need to look like this:

```
def selectAllRating():
    for i in range(1, len(var)):
        var[i].set(i)
```

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
var = []
for i in range(1, 5+1):
    v = tk.StringVar(value='')
    var.append(v)
    b = tk.Checkbutton(
        root, text=f'{i} Stars', variable = v, onvalue = i)
    b.pack()

for i in range(len(var)):
    print(i)
    var[i].set(i+1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a loop more easily if you name the `checkbutton` widgets. Then you can call `invoke` on each to activate them. Note that you'll have to `place` each button separately because `place()` doesn't return a value, and otherwise the variables like `cb_a` won't respond to `invoke` (you'll get an error). You can also `place` them using a for loop, so I've done that here

```
cb_a = Checkbutton(
    master,
    text='5 Stars',
    variable=starCheckBox[0],
    onvalue="5",
    offvalue=""
)  # note that you *don't* call `place` here any more
# I'm leaving out the rest to keep it short
cb_b = Checkbutton(master, ...)
cb_c = Checkbutton(master, ...)
cb_d = Checkbutton(master, ...)
cb_e = Checkbutton(master, ...)

# create an iterable of all the checkboxes
checkboxes = (cb_a, cb_b, cb_c, cb_d, cb_e)


def place_checkboxes(checkboxes):
    for x, cb in enumerate(checkboxes):
        cb.place(x=x * 100, y=20)


place_checkboxes(checkboxes)  # call the function to place the cbs
    

def selectAllRating(checkboxes):
   for cb in checkboxes:
      cb.invoke()  # 'invoke' selects and calls the command bound to each checkbox
```